# Do function for all files in folder

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to do this function for every workbook file that is in a folder. 
This script is parsing data from a single workbook. I would like to preform the same task for every workbook in the "attach" folder. Can this be done with a loop?

```
Sub ParseTimeSheets()
Dim FileName As String, FilePath As String, FolderPath As String

FolderPath = "C:\attach\"
FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xlsx"
FileName = Dir(FilePath)

Do While FileName <> ""


Application.ScreenUpdating = 0


 Dim WrkBookDest As Workbook
 Dim WrkBookSrs As Workbook
 Dim WrkSheetDest As Worksheet
 Dim WrkSheetSrs As Worksheet
 Dim WrkShArray As Worksheets
 Dim Rng As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range, Rng5 As Range, Rng6 As Range
Dim RngWeek As Range

Set WrkBookDest = ThisWorkbook
Set WrkBookSrs = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
Set WrkSheetDest = WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WrkSheetSrs = WrkBookSrs.Sheets("Title")

'selecting cells from Title sheet and parsing them to main workbook
Set Rng = WrkSheetSrs.Range("A1") 'week
Rng.Copy
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Set Rng2 = WrkSheetSrs.Range("A2") 'week range
Rng2.Copy
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Set Rng3 = WrkSheetSrs.Range("B4") 'employee name
Rng3.Copy
WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Set Rng4 = WrkSheetSrs.Range("B5") 'Title
Rng4.Copy
WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("D1").PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Set Rng5 = WrkSheetSrs.Range("B6") 'Site
Rng5.Copy
WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Set Rng6 = WrkSheetSrs.Range("B7") 'Loc ID
Rng6.Copy
WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
'For i = 3 To 9
'WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i).Range("A2:C57").Copy WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & (i - 3) * 56 + 1)
'Next
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

k = 1   'row counter for destination sheet
    'loop sheets 3-9
        For i = 3 To 9
             'loop rows 2-57
             For j = 2 To 57
                'if C is not empty
                    If WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3).Value <> "" Then
                     'copy A:C on this row to the destination sheet column G row k
                         WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i).Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Copy WrkSheetDest.Range("G" & k)
                            'increment counter for next row
    k = k + 1
End If
  Next
Next



'Close workbook sourse:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
WrkBookSrs.Close
'Sheets("sheet1").Range("M4") = date
Loop

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the loop but it is looping forever and getting stuck.

Comment: Just put `FileName = Dir()` over the `Loop` line...

Comment: I getting a message saying 'The name "Activities" already exists. Click yes to use that version of the name, or no to rename the version of "Activities you're moving or copying. Either option just does the same thing over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you just need to do this:

```
FolderPath = "C:\attach\"
FilePath = FolderPath & "*.xlsx"
FileName = Dir(FilePath)

Do While FileName <> ""

'your code here

FileName = Dir()   '<- add this... loops to next file in FilePath
Loop
```

Comment: I was doing my best to nudge them in the right direction and not outright give them the answer :P

Answer (score 2):

If you're opening excel workbooks you can use the `Dir()` function to find files. ([MSDN for the VB version, but it works the same in VBA as far as I can tell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx))  This little snippet will show me the files found in my `C:\` directory.

```
Dim str As String
str = Dir("C:\*", vbDirectory)
Do While str <> ""
    MsgBox (str)
    str = Dir()
Loop
```

Just modify your function to accept the path to the excel file as an argument and this should do the trick for you.

Note that I used the `vbDirectory` attribute for this example. You will likely not need to include this parameter as the default behaviour for the `Dir()` function is to find files with no attributes.

Comment: But I have already declared the file source, I would I modify my current code to set the  workbook source?

Comment: Given your current code all you need to do is find the next file in the folder right before you finish the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform any action for all files in a folder using a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` collection like this:

```
dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oFso.GetFolder("folderpath")

For Each oFile in oFolder.Files
    ' do whatever you like in here for each file...
Next
```